# How to create a cell using rowspan and colspan in a table

Tags: html, html-table

I have two rows and two columns in my table i have do the following using rowspan and colspan. There will be one cell on the corner. Please check the fiddle. I want to create below using table.

http://jsfiddle.net/UvjwJ/

I have to create it using table:-

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this. I have to do this using table not div or removing the border of td.
I dont have any idea to do that. I have tried to find this question in google but I can't find any.

Comment: Why? What's the usecase for such a markup? Is this an assignment or a real-world scenario?

Comment: I don't get the point, what is the problem?

Comment: Yes i am currently doing a project using php and if i want to change this table to div i have to do a lot more change. Is this can be done using table?

Comment: I don't think you can create that scenario with the current structure, If what you pretend is to create a L Shaped cell I dont remember having seen it before. It's better if you try to explain your needs and why you need that structure, and maybe we can think of a solution

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear (according to your comments to the answers). Do you mean that you have the above html structure, which you CAN'T change? So all we can do is to add css and/or attributes like `rowspan`?

Also, do you need text to be able to fit all around the corner cell? Or do you only need text in the left coloumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the only way you could achive what you want using only tables: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeVjU/ . It uses multiple tables and align (and it will work on all browsers, rowspan doesn't work in all browsers).

Moreover, keep in mind that a table cell needs to be a rectangle. You can not have other kind of cells.

```
<table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table border="1" align="right">
            <tr>
                <td>asdadasd</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        asdasdasdas das das das das dasdasd as dasd asd asdas dasd asd asd as dasdas dasd a
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, can you use css? And do you want the text to fit around the cell or is it enough with one coloumn?

You can of course do it partly:

Make the first cell a span over two rows. And then color up the border of the corner cell that is still there. Then you will have one long cell (a coloumn) to the left, and two cells to the right, where you can only see the top one.

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">A coloumn here</td>
        <td id="toprightcorner">A cell here with borders</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>A cell here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border: solid 2px black;
}

#toprightcorner{
    border-left: solid 2px black;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SteevenSpangsdorf/y47Ee/)

Comment: @BikashMondal. Oh, yes, I can see. Although there's a difference, since you commented: "i have some dynamic data for left rowspan's cell". Doesn't that mean that you want the rowspan; meaning that you want the left coloumn to be one whole cell?